# What does the annotation symbol "TR" mean?

Tags: analysis, notation, annotation

I've seen commentators use this symbol at the end of their analysis but I don't know what it means.  Does anyone know?

Comment: Do you have an example where this symbol is used?

Comment: ♘e2 ( 15. ♔b1 TR)  As you can see this is algebraic notation so it is not the TR mentioned in the answer by Adrenaxus

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with transposition? Like the sideline will transpose into the same position as the main line.

Comment: Good guess but I checked.  The lines where this comes after don't seem to  be transposing into anything that has been discussed before.

Comment: Initials of the author, editor, player, author of another book that was mentioned, or other possible source of the suggested move 15.Kb1? Needs more of the text.

Comment: Too Risky? Just my WAG.

Comment: Some context might help. Maybe  if you could give us the position in which the notation 15. ♔b1 TR is used, we could try to guess what it means.

Comment: Depends on the context. Could mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

[Descriptive Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_notation). It is an alternative notation for recording chess games.

From Wikipedia:

> Descriptive notation is a notation for recording chess games, and at
>   one time was the most popular notation in English- and
>   Spanish-speaking countries (Brace 1977:79–80) (Sunnucks 1970:325). It
>   was used in Europe until it was superseded by algebraic notation,
>   introduced by Philipp Stamma in 1737.

The abbreviation TR seems to refer to the spanish descriptive notation:

> The initials are taken from the equivalent Spanish words: dama for
>   queen, rey for king, torre for tower (i.e. rook), caballo for horse
>   (i.e. knight), alfil for bishop and peón for pawn. The files are named
>   after the initials of the pieces on the back rank, with those on the
>   queen's side being suffixed by the letter "D" and those on the king's
>   side suffixed by the letter "R". From left to right along the back
>   rank, this gives: **TD, CD, AD, D, R, AR, CR, TR**.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use such annotations at the and of an analysis though. It might refer to something else. Without having an example of where this is seen it is hard to tell.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense after a move in figurine algebraic as in his example.

Comment: I don't think the answer is correct.

Comment: After seeing the example (which was posted after my wild guess) I too think that my answer is not correct.